# checkbox combined with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to make a filter which works with a checkbox. When the checkbox is checked it should show some elements and when its not it should hide it.

This is the code I've got so far but I cant get it to work properly. Anyone who can help me out?

The html what got to hide/show

```
<li class="verwijder" class="kleding"><img class="aanbieding" src="images/jack.png"><span id="timer"></span></li>
```

The checkbox

```
<input id="checkboxeten" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="eten"><br>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  if (document.getElementById("checkboxeten").checked = true) {
        $( ".kleding" ).show();
    } else {
        $( ".kleding" ).hide();
    }
 });
```

Comment: you're testing the checkbox when the document is loaded, not every time they click it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an event handler for that

```
$('#checkboxeten').on('change', function() {
    $(".kleding").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

And you can't have more that one class attribute

```
<li class="verwijder kleding">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare using == not =.

Should be:

```
if (document.getElementById("checkboxeten").checked == true) {
```

Or:

```
if (document.getElementById("checkboxeten").checked) {
```

= is used for assignment.  == is used for comparison.

Also you will need an onchange event handler for your checkbox.  You should fire this logic not only on page load but also when the checkbox is changed I assume.  Or on a button click or some kind of event.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! it was not exactly what I was looking for but I learned of it atleast :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `<li class="verwijder" class="kleding">` with `<li class="verwijder kleding">`
2. Using my updated jquery code.
3. Here is working example (http://jsfiddle.net/yqkLpn6s/2/) [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yqkLpn6s/2/)